# Asus Touchscreen Laptop Linux. Would it work?

Tags: asus, windows-8, touchscreen

I got an Asus touchscreen laptop with Windows 8 pre-installed. If dual boot is a problem, can I just purge Windows 8, and make it a Linux only system without sacrificing the touchscreen feature?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your ASUS Laptop will work with Ubuntu. I think the touchscreen will work since this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HHEquvh7KI) on YouTube shows a ASUS Vivobook with Ubuntu 12.10 with the touchscreen in action. If you have a Vivobook or something similar, more than likely it will work.

You can dual boot if you want. **Keep in mind that your ASUS laptop came with Windows 8, which means it may come with a security feature called "UEFI Secure Boot" or "Secure Boot" for short. You will need to disable "Secure Boot" in order to get the laptop to boot from removable media, like CD's, DVD's and USB Drives.**

Comment: thanks, so If I was to delete windows 8 all together I should be fine, then.